# Mysql Select not working with date

Tags: mysql

I have the follow SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE 5 = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

And this is my table:
[image: Table Data]

And this is the table structure:[image: Table Structure]

How come it isn't finding the row which ID is 2?

`SELECT CURDATE()` returns:

> 2016-08-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your column name `5`:

```
SELECT * FROM staff WHERE `5` = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

without `` ` ``, mysql will take 5 as a digital number to compare with date not your column value.